# Zoom in on a page programmatically in GeckoView?

Tags: android, gecko, geckoview

When I double tap the page it zooms in. But how to achieve the same programmatically in a GeckoView?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API for this right now. You could try to fake some pinch events, maybe? What's the use case for this?